# UIview doesn't load with viewdidappear

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a tableview project which has a view, everything that I do in this view is controlled by "viewdidappear" method.

I added a new UIview which has "lines.h" and "lines.m" files.

I use this view to draw some lines and works god.

This extra view is located in to a scroll view because is to long to display in to iPhones screen.

The problem is that viewdidappear doesn't reload the uiview data, it only works with viewdidload.

I have to close the application and reopen it to get my data reload.

Answer (score 2):

First, try adding this line at the end of `viewDidAppear` method:

```
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

Or:

```
[_linesView setNeedsDisplay];
```

Second, Provide some more information. Post the code in `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear`.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `[self setNeedsDisplay]` in the lines UIView class to cause the view to redraw itself.